# Get a word between two patterns in preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to get the  percentage value of download from the following string.

```
[download] Destination: Kool - Get Noticed - Apurbo-7CggL03TTl4.mp4
[download] 100% of 1.60MiB in 00:21
[download] Destination: Kool - Get Noticed - Apurbo-7CggL03TTl4.m4a
[download] 100% of 164.86KiB in 00:01
```

For ex. only the value `'100' between '[download]' and '% of'`.
This is my code what I've tried so far

```
$file = file_get_contents("t.txt");
if (preg_match_all("/(?<=\[download\])(.*?)(?=\% of)/s", $file, $result))
for ($i = 1; count($result) > $i; $i++) {
    print_r($result[$i]);
}
```

But the problem is it grabs from the first line and outputs like

```
Array ( [0] => Destination: Kool - Get Noticed - Apurbo-7CggL03TTl4.mp4 [download] 100 [1] => Destination: Kool - Get Noticed - Apurbo-7CggL03TTl4.m4a [download] 100 )
```

If I can grab just before the `'% of'` that will be okay I think. Should I stick to this code for modifying or change the whole pattern?

Comment: So in this example with the text file, do you want to grab all numbers which are in the pattern: `[number]%` ? Also what would be the expected output?

Comment: Why not split on `[download]`, get the second line, and then run a regex ?

Comment: Actually not . Just the text between '[download]' and '% of '. I need the value for making a progress bar. So I don't need all the numbers. @Rizier123

Comment: I'm not sure in which line the progress status will contain. It may vary I think. @adeneo

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun So in your file there is 2 times a number in this pattern: `[download]' and '% of ` Do you want to grab the last or the first one?

Comment: I need both two values. Because the first one shows for video file and the second shows for audio file. That's why I'm using preg_match_all. @Rizier123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I first get your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) where every line is one array element. There I ignore new line characters and empty lines.

After this I go through each line with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) where I check with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) if there is a pattern like this: `[download] (\d+)% of`. If it finds the number I return it otherwise I return false and at the end I filter the elements with false with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) out.

```
<?php

    $lines = file("t.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $numbers = array_filter(array_map(function($v){
            if(preg_match_all("/\[download\] (\d+)% of/", $v, $m))
                return $m[1][0];
            else
                return false;
        }, $lines));

    print_r($numbers);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [1] => 100 [3] => 100 )
```

Comment: Why not just `if (preg_match_all(...))`  `print_r($result);`?

Comment: I don't really see what the point of the `array_map` and `array_filter` is for though? wouldn't `if (preg_match_all( '|(?mi-Us)(?<=\[download\]\s).*?(?=\% of)|', $lines, $result)) {
  print_r($result);
}` do essentially the same thing?

Comment: @l'L'l For sure you could do it all in one go with a regex. But I thought it would be easier to understand and more readable this way